# ADMob confuguration in ios app

Tags: iphone, ios8, admob

[image: I have configured admob first time with my IOS app. When I run the app in the simulator it looks like in the image.I don't whether admob is configured correctly or not.Any help will be appreciable.Thanks in advance.]

I have configured admob first time with my IOS app. When I run the app in the simulator it looks like in the image.I don't whether admob is configured correctly or not.Any help will be appreciable.Thanks in advance.
Here is my code :

```
self.viewAdvertisement.adUnitID = AD_BANNER_ID;
self.viewAdvertisement.rootViewController = self;
[self.viewAdvertisement loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it seems that you have configured correctly. And the latest Admob SDK now providing by default test Ads when running in the simulator. And when you run in your device then it will provide the real advertisement if ad identifier is not added in the test devices array.

So, just make sure you added the correct Admob ID which you registered using your account. The rest of the things are absolutely correct without any problem. Cheers :)

Comment: Thanks AppAspect for your quick replay.One more question : Do I need to do extra code to work in the device with live adds?

Comment: @Nirav no, as long as your banner id is correct paid ads will appear upon the release of your app. You can check this by testing your app on a real device right now also.

Comment: No need to do extra code to work in the device with live adds. When you run the project in device it will run the live ads. But to be on safer side please add Ad identifier in the test devices array otherwise Admob will consider fake impressions and at long term it can create problem and terminate you account. So, be on the safer side when you run on device.

Comment: @AppAspect really great answer for new bees like me, now I can deliver this app to client without worry about admob to check.Thanks...!